# Stop setInterval function written inside a useEffect when navigated to another page

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have an API that needs to be fetched every 30 seconds.The `UseEffect` written below in the code is for a component that gets rendered on home component. It's working well but if I navigate to any another page I need the API to not be fetched.
I'm using react-router and redux.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadCurrencyList())
    setInterval(() => {
        dispatch(loadCurrencyList())
    }, 30000
    )
  }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: return a cleanup callback from your `useEffect` function as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: does your component oresent in all other pages ?

Comment: No, it gets rendered only on home page.

Answer (score 2):

Do a cleanup in the return of useEffect :

```
useEffect(()=>{
const timer = setInterval(...)
return ()=> clearInterval(timer)
}, [dispatch])
```

Comment: What if I write the setInterval in a seperate function and call that function inside useEffect. Then in that case how to return the clearInterval?

Comment: use useRef() in this case. See the more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Store timer id in a mutable variable created with useRef() hook,
then use it in the component unmount code. Don't return clean up function from useEffect() dependent on [dispatch] as it will be executed every time dispatch variable changes.

```
  const timer = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadCurrencyList());
    timer.current = setInterval(() => {
        dispatch(loadCurrencyList())
    }, 30000);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect( () => () => { 
    if (timer.current) {
      clearInterval(timer.current);
    } 
  }, []);
```